# list, iterator definition make segmentation only in the Eclipse debugger

Tags: c++, eclipse, stl

I have a class `E_shop_file_data`.

On the following line:

```
std::list<E_shop_file_data>::iterator myfile_list_iterator_master;
```

I get a `*** Break *** segmentation violation` when I run the program in Eclipse debugger. When it is run without the debugger, it is ok.

When I change the previous line to:

```
std::list<E_shop_file_data>::iterator myfile_list_iterator_master = myfile_list.begin();
```

There is no segmentation error!
(`myfile_list`  is an `E_shop_file_data` object)

I cannot understand how is it possible to have a segmentation error in the first version.

Comment: what is the rest of your code which uses `myfile_list_iterator_master`? Obviously, in first case, the object is not initialized so it points to junk. if you try to use it, anything can happen.

Comment: 20.000+ lines. The error pop up in this line in the debuger  not ion the use of the iterator ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had to guess, I would guess that the debugger is trying to display the current value "under" the iterator.

Since the iterator has not been initialized (in the buggy version), the debugger attempts to follow something over the rainbow into Never-Never Land.  This is usually not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the segfault only happens while your program is attached to the debugger seems to hint that the debugger itself tries to dereference the iterator, probably to display the iterator's item in a watch window.

Since the iterator is invalid (you didn't initialize it), segfault logically ensues.

In the second version, the iterator is valid so the debugger can grab its item without trouble.

Answer (score 0):

If the debugger stops at that line, it seems possible that your code was optimized at some level. Like @syam said, you'd only get the segfault once that iterator was dereferenced.